# Adding a comma after text

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to put a comma after that text in my variable `$sd= Lol, Haha, Hehe, HayHay` like this, but with the code I have displayed below does not work the text format has to remain like this.

```
$sd = 'LolHahaHeheHayHay';
print $lol = ''.$sd.',';
```

Comment: in your string HayHay you want together but it not showing any logic. You can set logic before capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$s1 = "LolHahaHeheHayHay";
$s2 = preg_replace("/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/", ", ", $s1);

echo $s2;  //  "Lol, Haha, Hehe, Hay, Hay"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `,` before capital letter like below regex

```
<?php
  $String = 'LolHahaHeheHayHay';
  $result = preg_replace('/\B([A-Z])/', ', $1', $String );
  echo $result;
?>
```

This can easily be achieved using a regular expression:
a brief explanation of the regex:

- \B asserts position at a word boundary.
- [A-Z] matches any uppercase characters from A-Z.
- () wraps the match in a back reference number 1.

Then we replace with ',$1' which means replace the match with an [comma+ backreference 1]

[**SAMPLE HERE**](https://eval.in/506711)